# Convert an alphanumeric string to integer format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to store an alphanumeric string in an integer column on one of my models.

I have tried:

```
@result.each do |i|
  hex_id = []
  i["id"].split(//).each{|c| hex_id.push(c.hex)}
  hex_id = hex_id.join
  ...
  Model.create(:origin_id => hex_id)
  ...
end
```

When I run this in the console using `puts hex_id` in place of the create line, it returns the correct values, however the above code results in the origin_id being set to "2147483647" for every instance. An example string input is "t6gnk3pp86gg4sboh5oin5vr40" so that doesn't make any sense to me.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here or suggest a better way to store a string like the aforementioned example as a unique integer?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you overflow the integer boundaries. Maybe you need a larger data type, like 64bit integer (long)?

Comment: @IvayloSlavov Maybe..but that wouldn't explain why "t6gnk3pp86gg4sboh5oin5vr40" becomes "2147483647" instead of "060003008600401100500050040" like it should.

Comment: `"060003008600401100500050040"` is a number too large for an integer. Maybe even too large for a long. If the hex function just sets flags on the binary representation of an integer, when all flags are set you get the maximum (minimum for signed types) value. I would expect you to receive  `-2147483648` though. It definitely seems connected with exhausting positions in the binary representation of the result

Comment: @IvayloSlavov if you want to put this as an answer I'll accept it.  What I ended up doing was just adding a string column for use in cases where I was getting that id value format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering by request form OP**

It seems that the `hex_id.join` operation does not concatenate strings in this case but instead sums or performs binary complement of the hex values. The issue could also be that `hex_id` is an array of hex-es rather than a string, or char array. Nevertheless, what seems to happen is reaching the maximum positive value for the integer type `2147483647`. Still, I was unable to find any documented effects on `array.join` applied on a hex array, it appears it is not concatenation of the elements.

On the other hand, the desired result `060003008600401100500050040` is too large to be recorded as an integer either. A better approach would be to keep it as a string, or use different algorithm for producing a number form the original string. Perhaps aggregating the hex values by an arithmetic operation will do better than `join` ?